# sed didn't work with conditional if statement bash script

Tags: bash, sed, conditional-statements

i'm a beginner here in bash script, i want to ask something.

i've a conditional statement that compare the time in my computer with the time in the string, like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 
 skrg=$(date +%H%M%S)
 
 while IFS=':' read LINE do

         tanggal=${LINE//[:]/}
         if test $skrg -ge $tanggal 
         then
                 echo string
                 sed -e 's/$/LINE/' -i soal
         fi
 done < soal
```

The echo command is working under the if statement, but the sed not, it still add the LINE string even the if statement is wrong.

i am very confused about this problem, thanks for your help :D

---

example input:

> 01:12:14
>
> 07:08:45
>
> 22:10:45

output:
it should be like this=

> 01:12:14 LINE
>
> 07:08:45 LINE
>
> 22:10:45

but instead the output is=

> 01:12:14 LINE
>
> 07:08:45 LINE
>
> 22:10:45 LINE

Comment: Example input and output?

Comment: already add the example sir, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is,

```
sed -e 's/$/LINE/' -i soal
```

Because, `sed` will apply `s/$/LINE/` substitution in all the lines. That's why, You didn't get expected output.

**To debug:**

Add `cat soal` in end of `while` loop. Like this,

```
 #!/bin/bash

 skrg=$(date +%H%M%S)

 while IFS=':' read LINE do

         tanggal=${LINE//[:]/}
         if test $skrg -ge $tanggal 
         then
                 sed -e 's/$/LINE/' -i soal
         fi
         cat soal
 done < soal
```

**Solution:**

You need to use line number while doing the substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash

skrg=$(date +%H%M%S)
line=1

while IFS=':' read LINE
do
        tanggal=${LINE//[:]/}
        if test $skrg -ge $tanggal
        then
                sed -i "$line{s/$/LINE/}" soal
        fi
        line=$((line+1))
done < soal
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is messed up because you are overwriting the input file as you go along!

```
sed -e 's/$/LINE/' -i soal
```

This actually overwrites `soal`.

Answer (score 1):

To keep mainly your code

```
#!/bin/bash

skrg=$(date +%H%M%S)

while IFS=':' read LINE do

         tanggal=${LINE//[:]/}
         if test $skrg -ge $tanggal 
         then
                 echo string
                 echo "${LINE} LINE" >> /tmp/soal.tmp
         else
                 echo "${LINE}" >> /tmp/soal.tmp

         fi
 done < soal

mv /tmp/soal.tmp soal
```